# GitHub: repository not pushing the folder created with create-react-app

Tags: git, create-react-app, github-desktop

I want to initialise a repository with the following folder structure.

```sh
main-folder
  |-- project_backend
  |-- project-frontend
```

Just for reference, the backend code is python and the frontend folder was created using create-react-app.

When I pushed the repo using GitHub desktop, the project-frontend folder wasn't published, it wasn't even committed in the initial commit.

I tried all possible ways of creating the repo, but this problem still persists.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to check:

- git will not commit empty folders
- the `.gitignore` file may contain a pattern that excludes the folder

Comment: already checked those. folder has a ton of files, and gitignore doesn't exclude the files.

Comment: What does `git status` say, before and after you  `git add project-frontend`?

Comment: git status says everything is up to date. 
git add gives an error, I assume because you can't directly add folders, only files.

Comment: git allows you to add folders, and will recursively include all files under that folder.

what was the error message you received?
try `git add -f project-frontend` so that it will be added even if the `.gitignore` file excludes it.

Comment: it says:
### 
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.

### Is it because react initialises a git repo with create-react-app? If so, there are no .gitattribute or other git files in this folder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with react, but if it's a git repo, then there will be a `.git` directory that needs to be removed if you want `project-frontend` to be part of your `main-folder` repo.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem. I use GitHub desktop.
My folder structure was frontend folder inside backend folder.
I had made the frontend first using create-react-app which created a commit and a .git folder.

I used this:

> Delete the .git folder in your frontend folder.

It worked for me by simply doing this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. All I had to do to fix it was to go into my react app folder and delete the .git folder.

NB: If you have already push the project to the remote repo, you may have to delete the remote repo and recreate it.
Then open you local project folder and delete the .git folder, and then re-add the project to git by running git init and the rest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, although with Node.js not python.

Create-react-app seems to automatically create a .git folder

Only way I found to fix it was to delete the .git folder in the frontend folder.

I went to the folder itself in Finder (Mac user) and Cmd + Shit + . to see hidden files and then deleted the .git folder

Waited a few minutes and then it loaded as it should.